# Method to turn input into numbers is not working

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to make a method which converts certain inputs to a numbered output.

I am trying to make a method, which I call enumerate. It looks like this:

```
public static int enumerate(String user_input){
    int output = 0;
    if (user_input.equals("l")){
        output = 1;
    }
    else if (user_input.equals("r")){
        output = 2;
    }
    else if (user_input.equals("d")){
        output = 3;
    }
    else if (user_input.equals("a")){
        output = 4;
    }
    else if (user_input.equals("q")){
        output = 5;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I then tried to create a switch which looks like this:

```
switch(enumerate(user_input)){
    //moving left
    case 1:
        sharedData.setOffset(sharedData.getOffset() - 1);
    //moving right
    case 2:
        sharedData.setOffset(sharedData.getOffset() + 1);
    //moving all the way right
    case 3:
        sharedData.setOffset(74);
    //moving all the way left
    case 4:
        sharedData.setOffset(-73);
    //quitting
    case 5:
        running = false;
```

which should be changing certain variables based off of what is in user_input.
However, every time that I run this switch, it acts as if `case 5` is always true, even when it should not be.
Also, if it helps, when I tried to check what would happen if I ran `enumerate("l")` using the debug terminal (I'm working in VsCode), it ran an error saying `Cannot evaluate because of compilation error(s): The method enumerate(Thread[]) in the type Thread is not applicable for the arguments (String).`, which is weird because enumerate should be taking the argument of a string.
Any help would be great, just trying to figure this out.

Comment: Forgot to add `break` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put break statements after each case.  Otherwise, it is falling thru to the last one.

```
switch(enumerate(user_input)){
    //moving left
    case 1:
        sharedData.setOffset(sharedData.getOffset() - 1);
        break;
    //moving right
    case 2:
        sharedData.setOffset(sharedData.getOffset() + 1);
        break;
    //moving all the way right
    case 3:
        sharedData.setOffset(74);
         break;
    //moving all the way left
    case 4:
        sharedData.setOffset(-73);
        break;
    //quitting
    case 5:
        running = false;
}
```

Regarding your first code snippet, try it this way.

If the `user_input` is present it will return the index.  In this case `1` needs to be added since the indices are `0 based`.  But since it returns `-1`, adding `1` also works to return the default of `0`

```
result = "lrdaq".indexOf(user_input)+1;
```

Comment: Great, worked like a charm. I guess that I just needed to understand the syntax of switches more :)